# Why does my concurrent Haskell program terminate prematurely?

Tags: networking, haskell, concurrency

I have a UDP server that reflects every ping message it receives (this works well I think). I the client side I would then like to do two things:

1. make sure that I fired off N (e.g. 10000) messages, and
2. count the number of correctly received responses.

It seems that either because of the nature of UDP or because of the `forkIO` thing, my client code below ends prematurely/does not do any counting at all.

Also I am very surprised to see that the function `tryOnePing` returns 250 times the Int 4. Why could this be?

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
        s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
        hostAddr <- inet_addr host
        thread <- forkIO $ receiveMessages s
        -- is there any better way to eg to run that in parallel and make sure
        -- that sending/receiving are asynchronous? 


        -- forM_ [0 .. 10000] $ \i -> do
              -- sendTo s "ping" (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
        -- actually this would be preferred since I can discard the Int 4 that
        -- it returns but forM or forM_ are out of scope here?

        let tryOnePing i = sendTo s "ping" (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
        pings <- mapM tryOnePing [0 .. 1000]
        let c = length $ filter (\x -> x==4) pings

        -- killThread thread
        -- took that out to make sure the function receiveMessages does not
        -- end prematurely. still seems that it does

        sClose s
        print c
        -- return()

receiveMessages :: Socket -> IO ()
receiveMessages socket = forever $ do
        -- also tried here forM etc. instead of forever but no joy
        let recOnePing i = recv socket 1024
        msg <- mapM recOnePing [0 .. 1000]
        let r = length $ filter (\x -> x=="PING") msg
        print r
        print "END"
```

Comment: `forM` and friends are [found in `Control.Monad`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=forM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that when your main thread finishes, all other threads gets killed automatically. You have to get the main thread to wait for the `receiveMessages thread`, or it will in all likelyhood simply finish before any responses have been received. One simple way of doing this is to use an `MVar`.

An `MVar` is a synchronized cell that can either be empty or hold exactly one value. The current thread will block if it tries to take from an empty `MVar` or insert into a full one. 
In this case, we don't care about the value itself, so we'll just store a `()` in it.

We'll start with the `MVar` empty. Then the main thread will fork off the receiver thread, send all the packets, and try to take the value from the `MVar`.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = withSocketsDo $ do
    -- prepare socket, same as before

    done <- newEmptyMVar

    -- we need to pass the MVar to the receiver thread so that
    -- it can use it to signal us when it's done
    forkIO $ receiveMessages sock done

    -- send pings, same as before

    takeMVar done    -- blocks until receiver thread is done
```

In the receiver thread, we will receive all the messages and then put a `()` in the `MVar` to signal that we're done receiving.

```
receiveMessages socket done = do
    -- receive messages, same as before

    putMVar done ()  -- allows the main thread to be unblocked
```

This solves the main issue, and the program runs fine on my Ubuntu laptop, but there are a couple more things you want to take care of.

- `sendTo` does not guarantee that the whole string will be sent. You'll have to check the return value to see how much was sent, and retry if not all of it was sent. This can happen even for a short message like `"ping"` if the send buffer is full.
- `recv` requires a connected socket. You'll want to use `recvFrom` instead. (Although it still works on my PC for some unknown reason).
- Printing to standard output is not synchronized, so you might want to alter this so that the `MVar` will be used to communicate the number of received packets instead of just `()`. That way, you can do all the output from the main thread. Alternatively, use another `MVar` as a mutex to control access to standard output.

Finally, I recommend reading the documentation of [Network.Socket](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/latest/doc/html/Network-Socket.html), [Control.Concurrent](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent.html) and [Control.Concurrent.MVar](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) carefully. Most of my answer is stitched together from information found there.

Comment: Thanks, would there be any way to keep them unsychronized/non-blocking and still keep them both running at the same time but without starting them both as separate applications?

Comment: @JFritsch: Not sure i understood the "separate applications" part. Are you talking about the client and server?

Comment: Is there any way I could e.g. use the par combinator or such to let the main thread run through (whilst still continuing the receiver thread) in case it would be part of a bigger program in practice.

Comment: @JFritsch: `par` is for parallelism, not concurrency. If you want to keep both threads running, that's no problem. It's only when the main thread of the whole application is done that the other threads are killed. It's difficult for me to answer in more detail here since I don't know the specifics of your bigger program, but you'll likely have to use some synchronization at some point to communicate between threads. `MVar` is just one example of the many synchronization options available.

Comment: Does it in deed work on your PC? I get two strange errors when the MVar gets involved: `recv: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)` and `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation`, the latter should according to the book occur when there are cyclical dependencies of threads. I cannot find any.

Comment: @JFritsch: As I mentioned, the documentation for `recv` says it only works for connected sockets. The fact that it just so happens to work anyway on my PC is not something you can rely on. You want to use `recvFrom`.